# Handling logic and constants in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a date that gets displayed on my `View` that shows the last date a user logged in. They may have never done so. So it's passed as a `nullable DateTime`.

On the UI, I display it like this:

```
<td>@(u.LastVisit != null ? u.LastVisit.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "Not yet")</td>
```

But I have a few issues with this and think it might be bad practice.

Firstly, the view now has logic. (If null, show "Not Yet", else show the date). The View also dictates the date format. That format is already stored as a constant in a Constants file, accessible from my controller. And the text "Not Yet" should probably be a constant as well.

The only way I can see around this, is to return a String to the UI, and move that logic to the controller. But is that the right way to do this?

Comment: You can use a [DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute and set the `DataFormatString` and `NullDisplayText` properties and in the view use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastVisit)`

Comment: DisplayFor takes a Model, I think? I'm in a 'foreach', from a List<> property on my model. So I have the entity (u, in this case, which is a User in the List<User>. I'm not sure how I can use that User item in the DisplayFor. It seems to want a Model.

Comment: Then its just `DisplayFor(m => u.LastVisit)` (or `DisplayFor(m => m[i].LastVisit)` if its a `for` loop)

Comment: Perfect! If you make an answer, I can mark it as perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to the property and set the `DataFormatString` and `NullDisplayText` properties, for example

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", NullDisplayText = "Not yet")]
public DateTime? LastVisit { get; set; }
```

If you have already defined some constants for the format then you can use (for example) `DataFormatString = yourAssembly.Constants.DateFormat` where `DateFormat` is defined as

```
public const string DateFormat = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}";
```

and in the view use `DisplayFor()`

```
@foreach(var u in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => u.LastVisit)
}
```