# DisplayFormat using a Constant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a constant that is declared as:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
}
```

I have a DisplayFormat attribute on one of my model fields:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = Constants.DATE_FORMAT, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, NullDisplayText = "Not Yet")]
```

It shows an error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression

But this works:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

When I switch the hard coded format for the constant, it fails. Can this be done?

Comment: `public const string DATE_FORMAT = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}";` (`static` is not `const`) -ps. just updated the answer to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143694/handling-logic-and-constants-in-the-view)

Comment: Wow, you're on FIRE today, @StephenMuecke! Thanks. Worked!